# react-hook-form: how to add default values to the input field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-forms

In my project using a react-hook-form to create and update values. but the problem is whenever click on the update button shows an empty form without the data. The lines

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { useCountryCreate } from "../api/usecountrycreate"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"


export const CountryCreateUpdateForm = ({ defaultValues, onFormSubmit, isLoading }) => {

    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({ defaultValues });
  
    const onSubmit = handleSubmit((data) => {
      onFormSubmit(data)
    })

  return (

        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <div>
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input {...register('name')} type="text" name="name" />   
            </div>         
            <button type="submit" >submit</button>
        </form>



  )
}
```

When console this "defaultValues.data.name " then it shows the exact name value which I want to edit but is not displayed in the field.

[image]

Please give me suggestions, that will help me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely here that your `{defaultValues}` object is probably not properly configured. it should have a property called `name`. If it doesn't, hook-form can't properly match it to your input registered as `'name'` :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `defaultValues` object is not proper.

In your case I assume it's like this:

```
defaultValues =  {
  data: {
      name: '',
      category: '',
      ...
    }
}
```

It should be like this:

```
 defaultValues = {
      name: '',
      category: '',
      ...
    }
```

So change `defaultValues` object to the mentioned above **or** use the below code to set `defaultValues` in `useForm`

```
const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({ defaultValues: defaultValues?.data });
```